# Unable to import GDAL in Python 3.7

Tags: python, gdal, jupyter-notebook

I have installed GDAL using conda and it installed successfully. But when I try

`import gdal` in jupyter notebook, it is showing this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ee38efafc30b> in <module>
----> 1 import gdal

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gdal.py in <module>
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4 
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

and when I try `from osgeo import gdal`, it is showing this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-61e0eefce4de> in <module>
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

for GDAL installation i used this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

version information

```
-- python 3.7
-- conda 4.7.5
-- gdal 2.3.3
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried "import gdal"?

Comment: @bugmenot123 thanks for reply. I've sorted it out. Actually I had multiple python environments installed one in users and one in program data